# Can i use animate() for SVG <path>?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, path

Trying to use vanila `animate()` function for animating SVG **<path>** element

Path:

```
<path id="path1" fill="black" d="M30,30l 50,10 0,50"></path>
```

Js:

```
path1.animate([
    { d: `M30,30 l10,10 50,0` },
    { d: `M30,30 l60,10 50,20` },
    { d: `M30,30 l10,10 50,0` },
 ], {
    duration: 1000
})
```

Getting warn and none working:

Invalid keyframe value for property d: M30,30 l10,10 50,0
Invalid keyframe value for property d: M30,30 l60,10 50,20
Invalid keyframe value for property d: M30,30 l10,10 50,0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

js `animate()` is using the [**Web Animation API**](https://www.w3.org/TR/web-animations-1/#use-cases).
So you will need to wrap your d coordiantes in a `path()` function like in css path animations.

```
path.animate([
    { d: "path('M40 40 l10 10 50 0')" },
 ], {
    duration: 1000,
})
```

```js
let path0 = document.getElementById("path0");

path0.animate([
   // { d: "path('M30,30l 50,10 0,50')" },
    { d: "path('M40 40 l10 10 50 0')" },
    { d: "path('M50,50 l60,10 50,20')"},
    { d: "path('M30,60 l10,20 50,0')" },
 ], {
    duration: 1000,
    iterations: Infinity
})
```

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.pathAni {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.pathAniCss {
  animation: dAni 3s forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes dAni {
  33% {
    d: path("M40 40 l10 10 50 0");
  }
  66% {
    d: path("M50,50 l60,10 50,20");
  }
  100% {
    d: path("M30,60 l10,20 50,0");
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path class="pathAn0" id="path0" fill="black" d="M30,30l 50,10 0,50"></path>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path class="pathAniCss" id="path2" fill="black" d="M30,30l 50,10 0,50"></path>
</svg>
```

From W3C Docs: Web Animations; W3C Working Draft, 18 May 2021

> The Web Animations model is intended to provide the features necessary
> for expressing CSS Transitions [CSS-TRANSITIONS-1], CSS Animations
> [CSS-ANIMATIONS-1], and SVG [SVG11]. As such, the use cases of Web
> Animations model is the union of use cases for those three
> specifications.

[Check browser support for `path()`](https://caniuse.com/?search=path())
Firefox caniuse report 2022:

> Only supported on the clip-path and offset-path properties.

Some examples for testing browser support: [Animate SVG Path Changes in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/animate-svg-path-changes-in-css/)

Comment: This only works in Chrome. I was not aware that using the CSS `path()` syntax for the `d` presentation attribute is a part of any specification - can you point me to where this is defined?

Comment: @ccprog: thanks! Ive added some info regarding the limited support. Honestly, I haven't found a proper spec description on W3C or MDN– discovered this rather by accident.

Comment: For the quote above about SVG support in WAAPI I refer to a [blog entry I wrote last year](https://browser-unplugged.net/blog/waapi.en.html). In the light of your finding, I might have to amend my article, but the core conclusion seems to stand: only CSS-based features are ready to be included In WAAPI.